# How to properly display hindi/ gujarati in ubuntu

Tags: fonts

Ububtu 16.04.
Language support for Hindi and Gujarati enabled.
The issue is - hindi and gujarati does not display properly.
You can not read words that use "pra", "dra", "kra" etc. properly.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find any solution for words like pradhanmantri? I think I've to install again windows OS for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the file `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-prefer-hindi-gujr.conf` and give it this contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
        <alias>
                <family>serif</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lohit Devanagari</family>
                        <family>Lohit Gujarati</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
        <alias>
                <family>sans-serif</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lohit Devanagari</family>
                        <family>Lohit Gujarati</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
        <alias>
                <family>monospace</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lohit Devanagari</family>
                        <family>Lohit Gujarati</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

Comment: @AiriesTauras: I'm glad to hear. I'm not able to evaluate the effect myself. ;)

Comment: It appears the rendering differs from font to font. Previously,  I am not sure which font was used as default. And so it seemed like it did not render properly. (after your solution above) Lohit corrected the problems observed previously. However, it has its own incorrect rendering of few other words. Since then, I have played with various fonts and Lohit seems to be the font with least number of incorrect rendering. Search is on then for a font that would render every letter correctly. BTW, I am using http://akilanews.com for testing  a local news website in Gujarati. Thank you.

Comment: @AiriesTauras: Is it Gujarati you are focusing on? In that case you may want to reverse the order of the fonts in the config file, i.e. put "Lohit Gujarati" before "Lohit Devanagari" in all three places.

Comment: @Anwar: This may be something for you to look at.